# Show that it is equal to the integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How can we show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^n} = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^x}dx$$

Could you give me some hints??

Comment: Sometimes called the [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)

Comment: Now *that* is interesting. Thanks for the link, @ThomasAndrews. I never would have imagined that is true. Fascinating! +1 for both of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $x^{x} = e^{x\ln x}$, use $$e^{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

and integrate term by term.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!